# How to tell which party members a skill affects

Tags: darkest-dungeon

For skills which do not target an enemy, is there any way to tell which party members they affect, other than by selecting them in battle? There doesn't seem to be any way to tell except on healing spells, which specify "Heal" for a single target and "Heal Party" for the entire party.

If there isn't a method in-game, is there a list somewhere online?

Edit: the reason I want to know this is that an ability which affects the entire party is in effect up to 4 times more powerful than its base stats. Not knowing this in advance when choosing or upgrading skills means trying to compare potentially incomparable skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The only way to tell is in battle, or by researching outside the game. I recommend [the wiki](https://darkestdungeon.gamepedia.com/Darkest_Dungeon_Wiki).

While looking up the full list, I noticed some rules that apply for most abilities. If the ability does any of the following and does not say it affects the party, it is single target. Otherwise it is multi-target.

- Healing
- Stress Recovery
- Debuff/DoT removal
- Guarding

The exceptions are:

- The Houndsmaster's Cry Havoc hits the entire party
- The Plague Doctor's Emboldening Vapors hits a single target

Comment: I did try to apply HUGS as a mnemonic by making the U debUffs but I thought that was a bit silly. Even by my standards.

Comment: HUGS? That's awesome - I'm going to use that.

Comment: @Studoku U can be Unbuff

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to determine if a support skill is multitarget or not by clicking on the skill in question and then mousing over the characters. If a skill is multitarget, it will connect the green bars with a cross like symbol (+). If a skill is single target it will not connect the bars.

Note that some skills do not just affect the selected character but also the user (regardless of rank). This is usually listed when holding the mouse on the skill. (for example, Battlefield Medicine can only be used in rank 3 and 4 but can be targeted to any rank but will also always heal the Plague Doctor as well).

Comment: Are you able to add a picture of this? That would make it very clear.

Comment: Sorry, I realise my question was unclear. I already know how to interpret the indicators that appear during battle. This is more about preparing skills outside of battle, usually in the hamlet.

Answer (score 1):

If you play through Steam you can install "Buff Skill Type Indicator" mod ([Steam workshop link](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1626194380)). It adds indicators under skill icons like this:

[image]